# Protect dedicated server with cloudflare

Tags: dns, installation, cloudflare, dedicated

So I have an Ubuntu 10.04 based dedicated server with LAMP installed. I host several websites, but for now all websites are on same IP, configured using Apache Virtual Hosts.

So everyone can attack my server, etc by getting IP. I wanna protect it with cloudflare, but then I need to setup my server different. To use DNS I suspose.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Set name servers to cloudflare then configured subdomains on cloudflare to my server IP...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up each domain separately.